# Is a mouse click a WM_* message or a combination of up & down messages?

Tags: windows, mouse, windows-messages

I'm used to working with a Windows framework that provides events for things like a mouse click or a mouse double click.  Are click events a Windows construct (i.e. does Windows send a WM_DOUBLECLICK or similar message) or does it send WM_MOUSEDOWN and WM_MOUSEUP to applications which then do some math to decide if the event was a click or otherwise?

Comment: look up CS_DBLCLKS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645606(VS.85).aspx) The correct order of messages you will see for double click event are - WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, and WM_LBUTTONUP

Answer (score 1):

It's a combination of messages sent through the WindowProc(). The messages are WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, WM_LBUTTONUP for the left mouse button, WM_MBUTTONDOWN and so forth for the middle button, and WM_RBUTTONDOWN and so forth for the right mouse button. See the Windows SDK at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458632(VS.85).aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

A mouse click is not a combination of windows messages, but it can lead to, depending on the application that is clicked.
There is a huge difference between windows input and windows messages, as they are only a tool for some applications, used in many different ways, as explained on MSDN:

- [About Mouse Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [System Events and Mouse Messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I also provided an example that shows the difference clearly in my question [How could it work to use multiple cursors on one Windows client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549654/how-could-it-work-to-use-multiple-cursors-on-one-windows-client) It shows what messages are sent by clicking and that windows messages are often not enough to emulate a mouse click, but if they are, how they can be used.